# boost python: initialize C++ class that expects a pointer from python

Tags: python, c++, pointers, boost

I have a main C++ class Test of which member elements are continuously changed by other C++ classes. These other classes receive a pointer to the Test class in the constructor, which they should keep as a member. It is important that this is a pointer, and that all other classes all change the same Test object. A simplified version looks like this:

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
class Test {
public:
    int a;
    Test();
    Test * get_ptr(void);
    int geta(void);
};
#endif // TEST_H
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
Test::Test() {this->a = 4;};    
Test * Test::get_ptr(void) {return new Test;};    
int Test::geta(void) {return a;};
```

changer.h

```
#ifndef CHANGER_H
#define CHANGER_H
#include "test.h"
class Changer {
public:
    Test * t_p;
    Changer(Test * t_ptr);
    void plus1(void);
};    
#endif // CHANGER_H
```

changer.cpp

```
#include "changer.h"
Changer::Changer(Test * t_ptr) {t_p = t_ptr;};
void Changer::plus1(void) {t_p->a += 1;};
```

boost.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
#include "changer.h"
#include "boost/python.hpp"    
using namespace boost::python;    
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(pnt) {
    class_<Test>("Test")
        .def("get_ptr", &Test::get_ptr, return_value_policy<manage_new_object>())
        .def("geta", &Test::geta)
        ;    
    class_<Changer>("Changer", init<Test*>())
        .def("plus1", &Changer::plus1)
        ;
}
```

This compiles fine, but when I use it in python I get a segmentation fault with this code:

```
In [1]: import pnt
   ...: t = pnt.Test()
   ...: t.geta()
   ...: c = pnt.Changer(t.get_ptr())
   ...: c.plus1()
   ...: t.geta()
   ...: 
Out[1]: free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I got the part for the pointer from https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/PointersAndSmartPointers but I can't seem to get it to work. I would greatly appreciate some hints on how to do this.

Comment: The code is confused as to who actually owns the pointer. Both the python wrapper for `Test*` and `Changer` think they own the pointer and so both call free, thus causing the seg fault. See this question on who to deal with ownership correctly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112561/boost-python-ownership-of-pointer-variables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boost.Python: Ownership of pointer variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112561/boost-python-ownership-of-pointer-variables)